# The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

This question has already been asked many times, but I still don't understand why I keep getting this error.

In my controller I have this method:

```
//
// POST : /ObjectProducer/Edit/5
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(OBJECT_PRODUCER _objProd)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        m_Db.Entry(_objProd).State = EntityState.Modified;
        m_Db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("SearchIndex");
    }

    return View(_objProd);
}
```

But when I hit the `m_Db.Entry(_objProd).State = EntityState.Modified;` line, the error occurs. Can anyone explain to me what's wrong?

** EDIT **

Here's the controller method which initiates the "Edit" method (The "GET" method)

```
//
// GET : /PriceProvider/Edit
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
{
    OBJECT_PRODUCER objProd = m_ProductManager.GetObjProdByID(id);

    if (objProd == null)
    {
        ViewData["ErrorMessage"] = m_NoDataFound;
    }

    return View(objProd);
}
```

Comment: where or what is this `OBJECT_PRODUCER _objProd` and why are you now using that variable in the code below.. what is `_objProd`

Comment: You might also want to post the rest of your controller code. I think I know what's wrong, but I'll need to see more code to be sure.

Comment: OBJECT_PRODUCER is a class created from the database, _objProd is the object returned from the view once the user clicks the "submit" button, and the intent was to take this object and save the modifications in the database.

Comment: @IronMan84 Ok, I will try to add out what I call when the "edit" is called

Comment: The error is quite clear.  The data context is disposed.  You can't use it after you've disposed of it.

Comment: what's the scope of your DbContext

Comment: @Servy yeah, I think you are right, problem is that I'm fairly new to MVC-App and I don't know how and when the database is disposed. That's why I'm posting this question

Comment: @HerveS A database isn't disposed.  A particular connection to the database is disposed.  BIG difference.

Comment: Ah, ok. So if I resume, from the time I actually load the data and display it, and when I submit the change, the database connection has been disposed? Sounds like I now have 2 different connection, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to follow a couple steps and this should solve your problem:

1. On submit from user, you need to get the Entity from the dbContext that the user is editing.
2. Then update the values on the Entity from the dbContext based on the Entity the user submitted.

I'm using Entity Framework 5, and this is the code I use to update the original entity based on the updated entity the user submitted:

```
public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate, TEntity originalEntity)
    {
        ctx.Entry(originalEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(entityToUpdate);
    }
```

So I think in your case:

```
public ActionResult Edit(OBJECT_PRODUCER _objProd)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //this line might not be quite right, but basically 
        //get the entity from dbContext based on the id of the submitted object
        OBJECT_PRODUCER originalFromDbContext = m_Db.GetById(_objProd.Id);

        //set the values for the Entity retrieved from m_Db to the new values
        //submitted by the user
        m_Db.Entry(originalFromDbContext).CurrentValues.SetValues(_objProd);

        m_Db.SaveChanges(); //save changes
        return RedirectToAction("SearchIndex");
    }
    return View(_objProd);
}
```

Comment: And that made me understand all the comments people told.

Answer (score 1):

Try re-fetching the _objProd entity from m_Db.  The one you get in your post isn't actually part of your current datacontext, it is from the datacontext used in the Get version of Edit.

```
var _newObjProd = m_Db.GetObjProdByID(_objProd.ID);
```

Basically entities don't play nice across two DataContexts.  You need to load the entity again in the new datacontext.

Comment: Ok, right, but when I have it, what do I need to do with it? I have tried to change the fields and redo the m_Db.Entry line, but the result is the same...

Comment: Just update the fields in _newObjProd with any changes in _objProd and then call SaveChanges().  No need to change the EntityState.